# WARNING: Readline services not available or not loaded

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, readline, enthought

I installed ipython with EDM(Enthought Deployment Manager). When I launched ipython in edm shell, it warned that:

```
    (edm)bash-3.2$ ipython
WARNING: Readline services not available or not loaded.
WARNING: The auto-indent feature requires the readline library
Python 2.7.11 |Enthought, Inc. (x86_64)| (default, Jun 23 2016, 03:30:25) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

mac os, python2.7 .

Comment: There is a [specific section in IPython's quickstart guide](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/install/install.html#readline) regarding the fact that macOS provides `libedit` instead of `readline` and hence misses functionalities. You may be able to fix this via `pip install gnureadline`.

Comment: thank u very very much

Comment: Also please note that when edm begins to offer ipython v5, gnureadline will no longer be needed, so this issue will disappear.